# Scroll one record at a time in MySQL PHP using next button HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, button

I have not found anything useful about it on the internet and I have been trying for 5 days. I'm learning PHP on my own and trying to make some nice projects to bring to school. I have two buttons in my project: one to go back and the other to go forward into MySQL records.
My code doesn't work and I don't know why. I think the problem is with the $w array in PHP code. **

***I've found the $id variable's never incremented by 1 as I'd like, where is the problem?***

** is there a way of not storing data momentarily in an array?

```
    <form action="prova.php">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="indietro" value="<"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="avanti" value=">"/></form>


 <?php
$id = 0;
$db_host     = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "cherubini");
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM cherubini WHERE ID = $id+1 LIMIT 1;");
$w = array(200000);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $w = $row['Lemma'];
}
  if ($_GET) {
       if (isset($_GET['indietro'])) {
       } elseif (isset($_GET['avanti'])) {
         $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM cherubini WHERE ID = $id = $id + 1;");
         $w = array(200000);
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
           $w = $row['Lemma'];
         }
        echo ($w); 
       }
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You can use data table js and css.
May be useful for you.

2.You have to use `LIMIT` statement for get data.(pagination).

Like`LIMIT 1,1`

Comment: What is the output of $w array?

Comment: Just the first record (specific field) of my database, if I'm going to click next button again it doesn't go to next item of my database. My code was updated: I just changed the $sql variable